# How to refer properly to the end of classes at the college? (study, studies, learning)

Tags: word-choice

> "She comes to me every day when I am done with my studies / learning /
>   study."

Which of the words is more appropriate in the given context? (Considering that this is the end of the day at the college and we finished our day there.)

Comment: Two people down voted the post but no one explained what's wrong, then this tool lose its effect of improvement. Please, explain what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in college, and you have finished for the day, you might say:

when I have finished studying [in classes, in the library or even on the lawn of the institution.
when I have finished for the day.
when I have finished my classes for the day.

Studying is an activity whereby you learn new things. Studying is important if you want to earn a degree.

Careful with: **finished my studies** because that means to no longer be at college. To have earned a degree.

Also, to **finish learning** is wrong here for your meaning. One often sees: in life, one never finishes learning [new things].

Comment: Thank you! Do your suggestions are also for present simple tense (for habits)? (meaning that I have to say: "She comes to me every day when I have finished studying." (Or "when I have finish my classes for the day"). Isn't it?

Comment: When I finish is not When I have finished.